# What is the exact difference between strocastic gradient Decent, mini batch gradient decent and gradient decent?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am new to AI. I just learnt GD and about batches for gradient decent. I am confused about whats the exact difference between them. Any solution for this would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

All of those methods are first order optimization methods, only require the knowledge of gradients, to minimize fintie sum functions. This means that we minimize a function F that is written as the sum of N functions f_{i}, and we can compute the gradient of each of those functions in any given point.

The GD methods consists in using the gradient of F, wich is equal to the sum of gradients of all f_{i} to do one update, i.e.

```
x <- x - alpha* grad(F)
```

The stochastic GD, cinsists in selecting randomly one function f_{i}, and doing an update using its gradients, i.e.

```
x <- x - alpha*grad(f_{i})
```

So each update is faster, but we need more updates to find the optimimum.

Mini-batch GD is in between of those two strategies and selects m functions f_{i} randomly to do one update.

For more information look at this [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-mini-batch-gradient-descent-configure-batch-size/)

Answer (score 1):

Check this.

In both gradient descent (GD) and stochastic gradient descent (SGD), you iteratively update a set of parameters to minimize an error function.
While in GD, you have to run through all the samples in your training set to do a single update for a parameter in a particular iteration, in SGD, on the other hand, you use only one or subset of training sample from your training set to do the update for a parameter in a particular iteration. If you use a subset, it is called Minibatch Stochastic gradient Descent.
Thus, if the number of training samples is large, in fact very large, then using gradient descent may take too long because in every iteration when you are updating the values of the parameters, you are running through the complete training set. On the other hand, using SGD will be faster because you use only one training sample and it starts improving itself right away from the first sample.
SGD often converges much faster compared to GD but the error function is not as well minimized as in the case of GD. Often in most cases, the close approximation that you get in SGD for the parameter values is enough because they reach the optimal values and keep oscillating there.

Hope this will help you.